# 事前に変更できないHTMLに対して、後付けで(class名を付与する等して)CSS装飾を加えたい

Tags: javascript, html, css

**最終的にやりたいこと**
下記で、・で開始されない文字列(「あいうえお」と「かきくけこ」）に対して強調表示したい

```
<p>あいうえお<br>
<br>かきくけこ<br>
・さし<br>
・たち<br>
・なに<br>
・はひ<br>
・まみ</p>
```

**条件**
・HTMLタグを事前に変更することはできません
※liタグなどは使用できない。行数も順番も変動する

---

**質問**
・CSSだけでは無理ですか？ 先頭文字が・であるという条件分岐は疑似要素を使用してもできない？
・JavaScriptを使用すればできますか？ `「先頭が・末尾が<br>」以外の行の先頭タグ`にclassを付与すれば良い？ 後からJavaScriptでclassを付与できれば、CSSがHTMLに反映されますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

現状の CSS では**テキストノードの任意の箇所を選択出来ません**。JavaScript で動的に要素を追加し、そこに装飾を追加しておく必要があります。たとえば、 [`Node.childNodes` プロパティ](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-childnodes)で子ノードを取得し、その中で条件に合致するノードを [`Node.replaceChild` メソッド](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-replacechild)を用いて装飾を適用した要素と入れ替える、という方法があります。

今回は文書構造を変更出来ないという前提がありますが、本来であれば予め適切な要素によるマークアップを行っておくほうが JavaScript によってテキストノードを操作する負担が存在しない分だけ、楽になると思います。

```js
const p = document.querySelector("p");

for (const node of p.childNodes) {
  if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    const text = node.nodeValue.trim();
    if (!text || text[0] == "・") continue;
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = text;
    span.style.cssText = "color: red;";
    p.replaceChild(span, node);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>あいうえお<br>
<br>かきくけこ<br>
・さし<br>
・たち<br>
・なに<br>
・はひ<br>
・まみ</p>
```

Comment: CSS ではやはり出来ないのですね。ご回答いただいたJavaScriptで期待した通り動作しました